# org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type while fetching data - @OneToOne mapping with Embedded IDs

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables, which have the same columns as primary key. Eventhough the tables have same columns as primary key, based on the significance of information the data is normalised across 2 tables. I am trying to establish one-to-one relationship between 2 tables through ORM. Below are the structure of the tables and the entities,

Table A :  input_tables

SOURCE      TABLE_NAME  COL1  COL2  COL3
source 1    tbl 1       xxx   yyy   zzz
source 2    tbl 3       ggg   kkk   kk
source 3    tbl 2       xxx   yyy   zzz
source 4    tbl 5       ggg   kkk   kk

[Table 1: input_tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26xZt.png)

Table B : input_table_Structures

SOURCE      TABLE_NAME  COL4  COL5  COL6
source 1    tbl 1       xxx   yyy   zzz
source 2    tbl 3       ggg   kkk   kk
source 3    tbl 2       xxx   yyy   zzz
source 4    tbl 5       ggg   kkk   kk

[Table 2: input_table_structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZBRP.png)

InputTable.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "input_tables")
public class InputTable implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private InputTablePK inputTableKey;

    @Column(name = "col1")
    private String col1;

    @Column(name = "col2")
    private String col2;

    @Column(name = "col3")
    private String col3;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn (name = "source",  referencedColumnName="source",insertable=false,updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "table_name", referencedColumnName="table_name",insertable=false,updatable=false)})*
    private InputTableStructure inputTableStructure;


}
```

InputTablePK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class InputTablePK implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "source")
    private String source;

    @Column(name = "table_name")
    private String tableName;

   ....


}
```

InputTableStructure.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="input_table_structures")
public class InputTableStructure {

    @EmbeddedId
    private InputTableStruturePK inputTablesStructurKey;


    @Column(name = "col4")
    private String coalesedColumnOracle;

        @Column(name = "col5")
    private String coalesedColumnOracle;

        @Column(name = "col6")
    private String coalesedColumnOracle;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "inputTableStructure",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private InputTable inputTable;

   ....
}
```

InputTableStructurePK.java

```
@Embeddable
public class InputTableStruturePK implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "source")
    private String source;

    @Column(name = "table_name")
    private String tableName;

   ....


}
```

and I have a repository,

```
@Repository
public interface InputTableRepository extends CrudRepository<InputTable,InputTablePK>{

    List<InputTable> findAll();

}
```

Whenever I try to fetch data for InputTable, I get the below exception,

**org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class InputTableStructure. Expected: class InputTableStructurePK, got class InputTablePK**

Since both the classes have same columns as primary key, I tried to use the same Embeddable class as EmbeddedId in both InputTable and InputTableStructure Entities, i.e I tried to use InputTablePK class as EmbeddedId in both InputTable and InputTableStructure Entities, upon which I receive the below error,

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column inputtable0_.col4 does not exist**

What I am trying to achieve is to establish one-to-one relationship between both the entities, and query by InputTable, to fetch data of **table input_table as primary object**, and data of table **input_table_structure as a nested object**.

Please correct me if there are any corrections needed in the approach.

Answer (score 0):

But Entities do not have same @EmbededId you cannot swap them. If they are same use `InputTablePK` in both entities.

Comment: Hi Peter, Using the same EmbeddedId didn't work. Changing the column names did help, although it is just a workaround, not a solution.